# Why jQuery does not work in nested Ajax functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

While calling nested Ajax, which innermost ajax doesn't work. As seen in the following example, I 'm calling `getInnerResp` into `getResult`.

Normally, when I debug with firebug is works interestingly. I think it behaves as async false but I setted async property as false didn't work again. Furthermore, I tried to get result set using callback function in `getInnerResp` function. Unfortunately I didn't succeed in any way. Also ftbl variable in getResult function returns null. `getInnerResp` only returns followed result;

***Result***

```
<tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr>
```

***Javascript***

```
function getResult(year){

    var visible  = true;
    var table    = $(".tbl"), tbody = $(".result").find("tbody"), ftbl = "";
    
    table.find("tbody>tr").each(function(){
        var data = {
            course : $(this).find(".course").val(),
            year   : year,
            prog   : $(this).find(".program").val()
        }
        
        if(year.length < 1){
          alert("Year field can not be empty!!");
          visible = false;
          return false;
        }
        
        $.ajax({
            url : "result.php",
            method : "GET",
            data : data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            traditional : true,
            success : function(d){           
                tbody.append("<tr><td>" + course + "</td><td>" + d.enrolledStudent + "</td><td>" + d.failedStudent + "</td>");
                if(visible){
                    ftbl += getInnerResp(course, year);
                    console.log("inner" + ftbl);
                }
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("Javascript runtime error: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
    });

    if(visible){
        tbody.append(ftbl);
    }
}

function getInnerResp(course, year){
  
    var tbl = "";
      
    var data = {
        course : course,
        year   : year
    }
    
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        tbl += "<tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr>";
    }
      
    $.ajax({
        url : "course.php",
        method : "GET",
        data : data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success : function(json){           
            $.each(json, function(i, val){
                tbl += "<tr><td>" + course + "</td><td colspan='2'>" + val + "</td></tr>";
            });
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
      
    return tbl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
ftbl += getInnerResp(course, year);
```

you try to assign a value generated in future (async) to a local variable.

Try to move the task in the inner function, like:

```
function getResult(year){

        var visible  = true;
        var table    = $(".tbl"), tbody = $(".result").find("tbody"), ftbl = "";

        table.find("tbody>tr").each(function(){
            var data = {
                course : $(this).find(".course").val(),
                year   : year,
                prog   : $(this).find(".program").val()
            }

            if(year.length < 1){
                alert("Year field can not be empty!!");
                visible = false;
                return false;
            }

            $.ajax({
                url : "result.php",
                method : "GET",
                data : data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                traditional : true,
                success : function(d){
                    tbody.append("<tr><td>" + course + "</td><td>" + d.enrolledStudent + "</td><td>" + d.failedStudent + "</td>");
                    if(visible){
                        //
                        // do the remaing in the inner task....
                        //
                        getInnerResp(course, year, tbody);
                    }
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("Javascript runtime error: " + textStatus);
                }
            });
        });

    }

    function getInnerResp(course, year, tbody){

        var tbl = "";

        var data = {
            course : course,
            year   : year
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            tbl += "<tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr>";
        }

        $.ajax({
            url : "course.php",
            method : "GET",
            data : data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success : function(json){
                $.each(json, function(i, val){
                    tbl += "<tr><td>" + course + "</td><td colspan='2'>" + val + "</td></tr>";
                });
                tbody.append(tbl);
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });

        console.log("inner" + tbl);;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i solved my issue as you specify. i thought, ftbl already global variable in getResult function and i can fill it with getInnerResp function directly.

Comment: @GoranZooferic Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

In getResult function ajax success callback, 'course' variable is being used but it was not defined anywhere. It might be causing exception, which makes script execution to stop before calling getInnerResp.

Comment: it gets course detail through an textbox in table row $(this).find(".course").val()

Comment: needs to reference that as data.course but it was mentioned as just course in the code.